# Why can't this user post multiple YouTube links in one question?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

There's currently an issue with [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92792/in-lok-toph-beifong-is-shown-as-big-chief-of-police-and-in-another-season-it-sh). The OP is trying to link two different YouTube videos to illustrate their question, but every time they try, the two links somehow end up pointing to the exact same video. Because of this, it's somewhat unclear what they're asking and the question has already attracted a close vote, but I'm reasonably certain I can answer the question so long as they can post the evidence they're trying to post.

For now, I'm going to ask them to include screenshots of what they're asking about, which should be enough, but in the meantime: **Why can't this user include multiple YouTube links in their question?** Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) They are part of new user restrictions. A new user cannot post more than eight hyperlinks in their questions and answers.

From [Privileges section](/privileges/new-user):

> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than eight hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile.

This count doesn't include questions and answers from Stack Exchange.

These restrictions are gone when they gain 10 reputation on our site.

Similar question from Meta Stack Exchange : ["You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299048/357396)